# I have a number sequence that starts with 6 and 11. I want to know that their are infinite number's in this sequence.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a number sequence $$6, 11, ...$$
A number is in the sequence if you can add their factors, not including themselves and it is equal the product the number's non-zero digits.
I know that all prime numbers that only contain 0's and 1's are in this sequence cause the only factor other than itself is 1. and $$ 1\times(1\times(1\times(1\times(...(1\times1)...)))) = 1$$
So all primes with only 0's and 1's must be apart of this sequence.

I know 6 a is in this sequence cause $$1+2+3=6$$ $$1\times2\times3=6$$
I'm wondering is their always a kth term in this sequence for all natural numbers k? and are some natural numbers that are in this sequence and isn't just a series just $1$'s and $0$'s besides $6$?

Comment: Tossing together a dirty script, I'm getting the sequence as starting $6,11,101,778,10111,101111,197503,\dots$  I had used a particularly silly and inefficient way of finding the factors so I don't expect to get many more terms to the sequence in any reasonable amount of time.  In any case, that does answer a very clear "yes" to your second question.  As to whether or not the sequence is infinite?  Probably... it seems reasonable that there may be infinitely many primes whose decimal representation contains only $1$'s and $0$'s.  See http://oeis.org/A020449

Comment: So, for instance, $197503$ has proper factors $1,313, 631$ and we have $1+313+631=1\times 9\times 7\times 5\times 3$

Comment: One observation is that if $n = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$ is the unique prime factorization of $n,$ we have that $$\sum_{d \,|\, n} d = \bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{e_1} p_1^i \bigr) \cdots \bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{e_k} p_k^i \bigr)$$ so that the quantity you seek is $$\bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{e_1} p_1^i \bigr) \cdots \bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{e_k} p_k^i \bigr) - p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k} \tag{1}.$$ On the other hand, if $n = \sum_{i=0}^\ell a_i 10^i,$ then you require that the difference (1) is equal to $\prod_{a_i \neq 0} a_i,$ and it seems (naïvely) that this product is often smaller than (1). Cool problem, though!

Comment: Like @JMoravitz has shown, it might be worthwhile to check integers with short prime factorizations by large primes, e.g., $778 = 2 \cdot 389$ and $197503 = 313 \cdot 631.$ In this case, these numbers will be large, so the product of their digits will be large, and the difference (1) will be close in magnitude to the product of their digits because the sum of the prime powers will just be $1 + p_i$ for each prime $p_i$ in the factorization.

Comment: All repunit primes are in the sequence and it’s conjectured that there are infinitely many such primes.